# DataTables warning: table id=table-timsheet - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, datatables, permission-denied

I am receiving error,

> "DataTables warning: table id=table-timsheet - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"

when accessing the page which contain data tables.

Its a **Laravel5.8** application running on **php7.2**. The same files I have uploaded in other servers and they are loading fine.

When inspecting the code, *"Console"* tab shows the below given error.

```
"403 (Forbidden)"
```

I have cross checked the file permissions but they seems to be okay. (755 for folders and 644 for files)

If I am commenting the code below, then the error disappears but the data wont load.

The data should display in the data table as fetching from database.

Comment: If I am commenting the code below, then the error disappears but the data wont load.              <script>

  
  $(function() {
let tableTimesheet = $('#roster-table');
let dataTableTimesheet = tableTimesheet.DataTable({
        ajax: {
data: function (d) {
d.shift_date = '10';
}
    }


    });
 
});


</script>

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you are providing to the DataTables Ajax call?

If you are using a POST method, you need to incorporate a CSRF token. If you have Jquery enabled, you can use this to initialize.  Please note this also requires adding the CSRF token to a  block in the head.

```
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
      });
```

Altenatively, you can include it as a data parameter in the specified AJAX call:

```
data: {'csrf': {{crsf_token}} }
```